# Return value from Active Directory

Tags: c#

First i wanna start saying i am new to programming. I've created a form in Visual Studio with a textbox called tEmailAddress and a button bExport. When i put my username in the tEmailAddress field and press the button i want it to display a messagebox with the displayname field from AD.

Due to lack of C# knowledge i am unable to get the wanted result. No errors, when i click the button nothing is returned to a messagebox.
Please advise.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ReadFromAD
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryEntry()
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
            de.Path = "LDAP://OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com";
            de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
            return de;
        }

        String FindName(String userAccount)
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = GetDirectoryEntry();

            try
            {
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userAccount + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Unknown User";
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string debug = ex.Message;
                return "";
            }
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }


        private void bExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tEmailAddress.Text != "")
            {
                string account = tEmailAddress.Text.ToString();
                FindName(account);
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Return "debug" from your catch instead of returning "". Once that is done, let us know what exception are you getting.

Answer (score 2):

`FindName` returns a string but you never use it anywhere

```
string result = FindName(account);
```

you can then use the local variable result inside your `bExport_Click` method as you wish

Answer (score 2):

change `bExport_Click` to show the message

```
    private void bExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tEmailAddress.Text != "")
        {
            string account = tEmailAddress.Text.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(FindName(account));
        }
    }
```